# Setting Zero values back to NULL

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator

I'm working with ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop and OS Windows 7.

I need to set numeric vales from Zero back to NULL, but I can't from the field calculator.

I'm working with  a vector file and I need to display NULL in one column that shows 0 (Zero) as default value.

-------- Edit-------
I am adding the error messages that he received
[image: Error Message 1]
Translation:  An error occurred during the process.  Please consult the Geoprocessing Results Window to obtain more details.
[image: Geoprocessing Results Window]
Error at bottom, translation:  The values ​​of the selected column can not be set to null because the field in the database is defined as "Not Null".

Comment: Is it a shape file or a geodatabase feature class? I do not believe shapefile support null values.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you are using ArcGIS, and not QGIS, this is a simple operation.  It definitely can be performed in the Field Calculator.  I created a field, "test_num", type of `Double` as an example.  This is in ArcGIS 10.2 on Windows 7, 64bit.

Source Table - Data set to `0`
[image: Source Data]

Field Calculator:  Simply enter `NULL` as the value to be calculated.
[image: Field Calculator - NULL]

Result Table - Selected values are now `<Null>`
[image: Result Table - Values set to NULL]

--------- Edit -----------
Based on the additional screenshots you provided, the issue is clear.  You cannot set the values to `NULL` because you have specified that this column **Cannot** have `NULL` values.

Your best bet is to create another column that allows `Nulls`, and try this operation again.  If you are still finding an error, please modify your question with additional information.

Comment: I have tried that but is not working, it says something about an error ocurring while the calc was processing the data :(

Comment: If you are receiving an error message, that is the sort of information that is extremely useful to provide when asking a question.  If you don't, then people go on the assumption that you haven't tried the basic processes.  The more detailed you make your question with regard to what you have tried and what didn't work, the more likely you are to receive an answer that actually addresses your problem.  Please edit your question to include information about the error message.  A screen shot would be ideal.

Comment: I wish I have tried what ppl here were saying while helping me with solving this question. All I have done is what they ask me to do. Also the whole program is in Spanish, so what should I post? maybe you guys will don't understand that's why I write the traduction instead of posting a screenshot.

Comment: There are people on this site from all over the world.  If you post the error message as a screenshot and it is in Spanish, then also enter text below it with an English translation.  That would cover all your bases.  Obviously there is something we are missing as you are getting an error when you are trying the solutions that people suggest.

Comment: OK, here is a step by step of what I'm doing:
http://prntscr.com/4f49zt
http://prntscr.com/4f4ac5
http://prntscr.com/4f4ask

Is OK here or should I make nother question?

Comment: @EdixonGutierrez The answers here all relate to ArcGIS so I think you should edit your question here so that it only relates to ArcGIS for Desktop.  Then if you also need an answer for QGIS please research whether that has already been answered here first, and if not, then ask that as a [new question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: I'll post another question then, related with pycalc script, I think that'll be the solution, I hope you guys check it in a min.

Comment: The error messages provided all the information you needed to solve the problem.  You cannot set values to `Null`, if the column is set to NOT accept `Null` values.  I modified my answer to reflect as much.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this directly in the field calculator.

[image]

Comment: I can't make it work via Python in arcGIS, can I use the same script in qgispycalc right?

Comment: This is the script I'm using
http://prntscr.com/4f3w6s
But it shows this in the dialog box:
http://prntscr.com/4f3wjk

Comment: I am confused, you make no mention of QGIS in your post??

Comment: Sorry I though you could help me with that because both are using Python, but is OK, I can't make it works in arcGIS

Comment: No problem, I would recommend asking a separate question relating to QGIS.  Does the answer that I gave you work for ArcGIS?

Comment: I did edit the post and added that in the last line, would it be OK?

Comment: Great, I am still confused why none of these answers are working for you in ArcGIS.  Are you getting error messages or encountering some other issue?

Comment: When @Aaron recommended asking a separate question, I am going to assume he meant creating a new question related to setting a field to null in QGIS.  This is different than editing your existing ArcGIS related question to include something about a different software package.  This site provides the best results when the questions are focused, both in topic and application, and provide as much detail as possible.  I second his recommendation to make a new question about setting fields to null in QGIS, and including what you have already tried in that regard.

Comment: Based on your edits, it appears you will have to write the results to a new field because your field is not configured to accept null values.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new integer field. Then calculate your existing field with the newly created one.

[image]

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work

http://prntscr.com/4f3qm1
http://prntscr.com/4f3qwo

And I need the field to be in double type, I saw it once from a file a person did where I work, but that person is not here anymore :(

Answer (score 3):

As shown in the image below...

-Select the records you want to null

-In Field Calculator, set the Parser to "Python"

-Type (case sensitive): None

-Click OK

[image]